# Steam will not install on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: steam

I downloaded steam, the file is called steam_latest.deb. Ubuntu has me authenticate and type in my password, but when I do, it starts installing for a quarter of a second, then stops immediately. It doesn't go above 0%. I'm new to Ubuntu, so I'm fairly lost on what to do.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you try to install this from the command line?  Open a terminal and type `cd Downloads` and then `sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb` and put the output here.

Comment: The installer is just a small "bootstrapper" that downloads the rest of the client where-ever it's run. Have you searched for `steam` or `steam-launcher` to run the installer? Try `which steam` in the terminal, but press Tab to complete steam after typing stea, and see if it does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have installed it by clicking on the deb file, you may want to try a different approach. You may try installing it by the following command (in a terminal window)

cd directory_where_the_file_resides(usually downloads)

sudo dpkg -i file.deb

(or alternatively: sudo dpkg -i /home/downloads/downloaded_file.deb)

Alternatively, you can go to the software center and try installing it from there. It has worked for me.